# Lua substitution of double quotation mark

Tags: luatex, lua

I'm playing with Lua substitutions and have realised I can't figure out how to escape quotation marks for double quotation marks (U+0022) and substitution code that works for *every other* character has utterly failed in this case, leaving intact the normal character. Is there a way to escape it?  Nonworking example below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local uchar = unicode.utf8.char
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "qalt",
    type = "substitution",
    data =
    {
   " = "a",
    },
  }
  \end{luacode}
  \usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Crimson}
\begin{document}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+qalt}}
  (Questions about " NASDAQ.) That’s better.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `[0x0022] = "a",`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm afraid, which is confusing because it should... https://imgur.com/a/mCSf5mS

Comment: hm, try with `\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+qalt;-tlig;}`. But I wonder why the ligatures are off on my system.

Comment: `" = "a"` is not valid lua table syntax; you would need `['"'] = "a"` I think, but part of the problem, as Ulrike's suggestions make clear, is that the substitution of `“` or `”` (so called smart quotes, U+201C, U+201D) for `"` is happening prior to the handler being applied, so you either need to disable that substitution (per the suggestion) or use  `“ = "a", ” = "a"`.